# Merge txt. files by powershell nane of file as value

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Good day

I have multiple unique txt files in folder and i need to merge them in one txt file with name of file

exaple what i need :

```
value1;filename1
value2;filename1
value1;filename2
value2;filename2
value3;filename2 
value4;filename3
...   ;  ...
```

I have this :

```
dir C:\Users\ltester\Desktop\test\* -include *.txt -rec | gc | out-file C:\Users\ltester\Desktop\result.txt
```

which give to me all values into one file but without name of file.

Thank you for help me to setup powershell code which give me values from multiple txt files in to one file with names of files.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
Get-Childitem C:\Users\ltester\Desktop\test\* -include '*.txt' -rec | % {"$(Get-Content $_);$_.Name"} | Out-file C:\Users\ltester\Desktop\result.txt -Append
```

This writes the content of each file to result.txt with the name of the file.

**Explanation:**

`%` - foreach file given by the pipe

`"$(Get-Content $_)` - Write the Content of the file given by the pipe

`;$_.Name` - Append `;` and the name of the file given to the ouput

Comment: @ted yeah that is the expected behaviour. if this is not what you wanted you have to elaborate more.

Comment: Get-ChildItem C:\Users\ltester\Desktop\test\* -include *.txt |
%{$FILENAME=$_.BaseName;$COUNT=1;get-content $_ |
%{"$FILENAME"+"$COUNT"+" " + "$_";$COUNT++}}|
Out-File C:\Users\ltester\Desktop\result.txt

Answer (score 1):

Presuming the values are the line content from the text files try:

```
forEach ($file in (gci filename[1-3])){gc $file|%{"{0};{1}" -f $_,$file.Name}}
```

Sample ouput

```
value1;filename1
value2;filename1
value1;filename2
value2;filename2
value3;filename2
value4;filename3
```

Here the verbose version without aliases:

```
ForEach ($file in (Get-ChildItem filename[1-3] )){
    Get-Content $file | ForEach-Objet {
        "{0};{1}" -f $_,$file.Name
    }
}
```